# Selenium Python Webdriver: File not Found error

Tags: python, selenium, file-not-found

I had a python script that up until a few days ago worked. It submits a file to a website, waits for the analysis to finish, then prints out the XML output. The file that it uploads can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gklhv3s8yemc67v/2ffk.md.300.p0.pdb?dl=0)

```
import sys
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time

path=os.getcwd()+"/"
filename=sys.argv[1]
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
driver.get("http://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/pisa")
driver.find_element_by_name("start_server").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='id_coorfile']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"file\"]").send_keys(path+filename)
driver.find_element_by_name("btn_upload").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("btn_submit_interfaces").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("btn_interface_details").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("downloadXML").click()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(3)
print driver.page_source
driver.close()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.close()
```

When running this code two days ago, it suddenly gave me an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: File not found: /home/lstark/research/chemokines/PDBePISA/2ffk.md.300.p0.pdb
```

I use os.getcwd() and use sys.argv[1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gklhv3s8yemc67v/2ffk.md.300.p0.pdb?dl=0) so I can tab-complete the file name to make sure I'm not typing it incorrectly, but I still get the same error. The file is in the same directory as the script. I've tested the path+filename in python, and can open and read the file without a problem. I tested it on another computer as well and hit the same error. I've tested the script line by line and the error occurs at

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"file\"]").send_keys(path+filename)
```

I am working in Ubuntu 16.04, using selenium 3.5.0, python 2.7.12, and Firefox 55.0.2.

Is anyone able to reproduce this error and can anyone offer some advice on how to get Selenium to find the path to upload the file?

Comment: If others have a similar issue, I was able to get a work around by using Chrome, but I would like to find a solution to fix the issue with Firefox if possible.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this on Firefox? I have the same issue. Used to work before, now it doesn't.

Comment: I didn't find a direct solution. I was able to get it to work by using a Windows system that had an older version of Firefox. Version 54 still works with Selenium, so if you can get it to downgrade properly, then it should work.